# c to mips source and dest pointer

Tags: c, mips

```
#include <stdio.h>

int source[] = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 0};
int dest[10];

int main ( ) {
    int k;
    for (k=0; source[k]!=0; k++) {
    dest[k] = source[k];
    }
    printf ("%d values copied\n", k);
    return 0;
}
```

this is the c code

pretty simple, it just copies the values of the array to the dest array unless it's 0

now, the problem is with the mips code

```
    .file   1 "arrcopy.c"
    .globl  source
    .data
    .align  2
source:
    .word   3
    .word   1
    .word   4
    .word   1
    .word   5
    .word   9
    .word   0
    .rdata
    .align  2
$LC0:
    .ascii  "%d values copied\n\000"
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .ent    main
main:
    .frame  $sp,24,$31      # vars= 0, regs= 1/0, args= 16, extra= 0
    .mask   0x80000000,-8
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    subu    $sp,$sp,24
    sw  $31,16($sp)
    jal __main
    la  $9,source
    lw  $2,0($9)
    move    $8,$0
    beq $2,$0,$L8
    move    $7,$0
    la  $10,dest
$L6:
    addu    $8,$8,1
    sll $3,$8,2
    addu    $5,$7,$9
    addu    $2,$3,$9
    addu    $6,$7,$10
    lw  $4,0($2)
    move    $7,$3
    lw  $3,0($5)
    #nop
    sw  $3,0($6)
    bne $4,$0,$L6
$L8:
    la  $4,$LC0
    move    $5,$8
    jal printf
    lw  $31,16($sp)
    move    $2,$0
    addu    $sp,$sp,24
    j   $31
    .end    main

    .comm   dest,40
```

i can't even tell what the source pointer is and the destination pointer

not even sure about when the loop starts

i am thinking it starts at $L6

what instruction is it using to load the address of the source and dest pointers?

like if you guys can find the loop can you give me an idea of what each line is doing?

it looks so different than by hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added some comments to explain the disassembly:

```
  la  $9,source     # The source pointer
  lw  $2,0($9)      # Load source[0]
  move    $8,$0     # "next_k"
  beq $2,$0,$L8     # skip the loop if source[0]==0
  move    $7,$0     # k
  la  $10,dest      # destination pointer
$L6:
  addu    $8,$8,1   # Increase the next_k counter
  sll $3,$8,2       # scale to a word offset (multiply by 4)
  addu    $5,$7,$9  # $5 = &source[k]
  addu    $2,$3,$9  # $2 = &source[next_k]
  addu    $6,$7,$10 # $6 = &dest[k]
  lw  $4,0($2)      # $4 = source[next_k]
  move    $7,$3     # k = next_k (i.e. k++)
  lw  $3,0($5)      # $3 = source[k]
  #nop
  sw  $3,0($6)      # dest[k] = source[k]
  bne $4,$0,$L6     # Loop until source[next_k]==0
$L8:
```

Comment: this is literally the best thing ever

Comment: is the command that is loading the address addu and not la? like what instruction is used to load the address of source and dest
pointers?

Comment: `la` is used to load the pointers, and `addu` is used to add offsets to the pointers.